# overbrace but leave spacing in math unaffected

Tags: spacing, amsmath, braces

I would like to use an overbrace, but I do not want how much text I put in the overbrace to affect the spacing of the math (i.e. I don't want the the "a" and the "b" to get further apart in the following example):

```
$\frac{a-\overbrace{b^d}^{\text{'d' here stands for 'dummy variable', it is not an exponent}}}{c}$
```

Any ideas? This particular example is pretty silly and I would not do it in practice, but it is just to make things simple.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the situation, maybe you can use `\mathclap` from `mathtools`.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  $\frac{a-\overbrace{b^d}^{\mathclap{\text{'d' here stands for 'dummy variable', it is not an exponent}}}}{c}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$
  \frac{a-\overbrace{b^d}^{
    \hidewidth
    \text{'d' here stands for 'dummy variable', it is not an exponent}
    \hidewidth
  }}{c}
$
\end{document}
```

So, the `\hidewidth`, well, hides the width.

Comment: `\text` is defined in `amstext` whis would be automatically loaded by `amsmath`. It cannot be seen in the question, but the the tag {amsmath} has been used.